# Powershell - Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]

Tags: csv, powershell

I want to add the profile pictures of the exchange to our users in Active Directory.

I tried to do this in Powershell, but cause I'm pretty new to Powershell i'm already stucking.

My Script:

```
$Name = @()
$Photo = @()

Import-Csv C:\temp\adusers.csv |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Name += $_.DisplayName
        }
Import-Csv C:\temp\photolinks.csv |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Photo += $_.PSChildName
        }

$Name | ForEach-Object {
            Where $Photo -Like "*$Name*" {
                Set-UserPhoto "$Name" -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("F:\1 path\" + $Photo))
            }
        }
```

I created a ps script to get all our AD Users before and I created a list of our userphotos with gci before as well. I exported those results in a csv and I now want to import thos data and tell Powershell add for every User in the List adusers a photo with Set-UserPhoto.

The error message I got is the following:

```
Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At C:\Users\user1\Desktop\setuserphoto.ps1:14 char:13
+             Where $Photo -Like "*$Name*" {
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Your `Where` line should be `If ($Photo -Like "*$Name*") {`.

Comment: Wow thanks I didnt realize that. The script is now running throught without an error message. But the pictures are not set. Do you have an Idea if I have a error in my ForEach-Object loop?

Comment: Also: Depending on the size of your input CSV, you may find a vast performance gain by setting ```$Name = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList``` and instead of ```$Name += $_.Something``` use ```$Name.Add($_.Something)``` - and do the same with ```$Photo```. It will [save you lots of time](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/09/16/powershell-performance-the-operator-and-when-to-avoid-it/) if you have lots of objects.